# How to build a launcher for my iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios5, launcher

I'm trying to build an homepage launcher for my app... 
Something like the one from [Three20](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher).

[image]

**I don't want to reinvent the wheel**, but solutions like Three20 are not what I'm searching for: they are not updated to the latest iOS systems or devices (retina, ARC, iOS5/6) and they do much more than what I need (I basically need a set of buttons with a label that rotate on device rotation).

Right now I'm trying to build a 2x3 buttons grid that rotates on device rotation, but the code looks pretty crappy and I steel need to add iPhone5 support...

```
- (void) updateLayoutForNewOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 59, 130, 80);
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(170, 59, 130, 80);
        button3.frame = CGRectMake(20, 176, 130, 80);
        button4.frame = CGRectMake(170, 176, 130, 80);
        button5.frame = CGRectMake(20, 293, 130, 80);
        button6.frame = CGRectMake(170, 293, 130, 80);

        label1.frame  = CGRectMake(20, 147, 130, 21);
        label2.frame  = CGRectMake(170, 147, 130, 21);
        label3.frame  = CGRectMake(20, 264, 130, 21);
        label4.frame  = CGRectMake(170, 264, 130, 21);
        label5.frame  = CGRectMake(20, 381, 130, 21);
        label6.frame  = CGRectMake(170, 381, 130, 21);
    } else {
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 59, 130, 60);
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(177, 59, 130, 60);
        button3.frame = CGRectMake(328, 59, 130, 60);
        button4.frame = CGRectMake(20, 155, 130, 60);
        button5.frame = CGRectMake(177, 155, 130, 60);
        button6.frame = CGRectMake(328, 155, 130, 60);

        label1.frame  = CGRectMake(20, 127, 130, 21);
        label2.frame  = CGRectMake(177, 127, 130, 21);
        label3.frame  = CGRectMake(328, 127, 130, 21);
        label4.frame  = CGRectMake(20, 223, 130, 21);
        label5.frame  = CGRectMake(177, 223, 130, 21);
        label6.frame  = CGRectMake(328, 223, 130, 21);
    }
}
```

Is the "place stuff, rotate it" approach the only way to build this kind of component? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Decide on the minimum size of a button, figure how many of them you can fit onto the available rect, divide it into a grid, and do some layout.

Comment: If you're targeting only iOS 6, take a look at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)...

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into it, but then I prefer to target at least iOS 5.

Comment: Those hardcoded constants make me cry. Use maths (remember division from primary school?) and a for loop to populate the view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the button and the label inside a view.
Then, on rotate you have to rearrange just the views.

Furthermore, you can use a `for` to rearrange them, so you can get that effect with a little code.

```
-(void)setScreenIconsToInterfaceRotation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    NSArray * viewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1,view2,view3,view4,view5,view6, nil];  

    int currentIndex = 0;

    for (UIView * currentView in ViewsArray) {

        int x;
        int y;
        int xseparation = 20;
        int yseparation;
        int height;
        int width = 130;
        if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        { 

            x = currentIndex %2;
            y = currentIndex /2;
            height = 101;
            if (currentIndex < 2) {
                yseparation = 59;
            } else {
                yseparation = 16;
            }

        } else {
            x = currentIndex %3;
            y = currentIndex /3;
            height = 81;
            if (currentIndex < 3) {
                yseparation = 59;
            } else {
                yseparation = 15;
            }

        }

        [currentView setFrame:CGRectMake(x*width+((x+1)*xseparation), y*height+((y+1)*yseparation), width, height)];


        currentIndex++;
        }

}
```

This is the code for your example

then for ios6

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
        [self setScreenIconsToInterfaceRotation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
    }
```

and ios5

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {

    [self setScreenIconsToInterfaceRotation:toInterfaceOrientation]; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You maybe want to code this yourself, but there's a fantastic open-source launcher here:

https://github.com/fieldforceapp/openspringboard